# Running the same jar file many times simultaneously with different arguments

Tags: java

I am trying to run the same jar multiple times simultaneously with different command line arguments

Currently I am running below in cmnd prompt

java -jar xyz.jar args1 & java -jar xyz.jar args2

I am running a particular function inside the jar for some duration. But the jar with args1 gets executed more no. of times compared with the args2. Is there any way where the jar gets executed almost same no. of times with different arguments at the same time

Comment: I don't really get your conclussion, it looks like both will be run once. It sounds like you want to write a script for your OS, which os are you using?

Comment: I am running on linux OS. I have a function inside the jar that hits an api for a certain duration. Both the jars are running at once, but it seems the first one hits more requests compared to the second one. Is there any way, I can ensure that same no. of requests are hit from both the jar(same jar with different args) at same time.

Comment: This is impossible to solve with the information you've provided. It very well could be `java -jar app.jar --make-10-requests` vs `java -jar app.jar --make-1-request` you haven't provided any code. All we know is you're running a program twice with different arguments.